# GPS background tracking in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, gps, background-process

Here, at work, I am working on an app which (attempt to) track user location in the background.
(Using C# and Xamarin / MonoTouch)

I tried to enable background tracking with the 3 following steps:

1. I updated the info.plist to have: BackgroundMode-On (Location Update, Background Fetch)
2. in my AppDelegate, call UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(Interval.TotalSeconds);
3. Also registered location change with location manager:

   static CLLocationManager LocMgr = new CLLocationManager();
     // ...
     LocMgr.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();
     if (CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled)
     {
        LocMgr.StartMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges();
        LocMgr.LocationsUpdated += LocationsUpdated;
     }

However, despite all of that, in a whole night I only get 10 update (Interval is set to 1 minute!!!)
And I also went for a 10 minutes walk and I didn't get a single update!

Any clue on what I could be missing?
Cheers!  Big Grin | :-D

Comment: the background fetch interval is nothing to do with location updating. If you are using significant location change monitoring then you will only get an update if the device moves about 500m or more.

Comment: Yes, you right! Thanks! :)

As per a link now deleted by moderators I did fix that by, among other things, just as you said, using StartUpdatingLocation() 

Now another problem I have is, I want to write (in the background) the user's location and date time, I get a file access exception when open the disk file! 
Any idea there?

Comment: You need to check the level of file protection that is applied to your file/directory - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Protection_Values